# can't navigate SimpleXMLElement data

Tags: simplexml

I am trying to consume a REST web service.

Below is the code
//set token in custom header

```
$options = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"authorization:$cj_token\r\n"));

$context=stream_context_create($options);
$mymerchants="https://advertiser-lookup.api.cj.com/v3/advertiser-lookup?advertiser-ids=joined";
$sxml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($mymerchants,false,$context));

foreach ($sxml->advertisers->advertiser as $advertiser) {
    print_r($advertiser);
    //$a = $advertiser->advertiser-id;
    $language = $advertiser->language;      
    //echo "<BR>id=".$a;
    echo "<BR>langauge=".$language;
    echo "<BR><BR>";
}
```

The value of $sxml is as below
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [advertisers] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [total-matched] => 496 [records-returned] => 25 [page-number] => 1 ) [advertiser] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [advertiser-id] => 129899 [account-status] => Active [seven-day-epc] => 7.81 [three-month-epc] => 9.66 [language] => en [advertiser-name] => BOOKSAMILLION.COM [program-url] => xhttp://www.booksamillion.com [relationship-status] => joined [mobile-tracking-certified] => false [network-rank] => 4 [primary-category] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [parent] => Books/Media [child] => Books ) [performance-incentives] => false [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [action] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Sale [type] => sale [id] => 266 [commission] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [default] => 5.00% ) ) ) [link-types] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [link-type] => Array ( [0] => Text Link [1] => Banner [2] => DeepLink [3] => Advanced Link ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [advertiser-id] => 79362 [account-status] => Active [seven-day-epc] => 19.94 [three-month-epc] => 16.17 [language] => en [advertiser-name] => Testclear.com [program-url] => xhttp://www.testclear.com [relationship-status] => joined [mobile-tracking-certified] => false [network-rank] => 1 [primary-category] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [parent] => Health and Wellness [child] => Health Food ) [performance-incentives] => true [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [action] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Sale [type] => sale [id] => 234 [commission] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [default] => 12.00% ) ) ) [link-types] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [link-type] => Array ( [0] => Text Link [1] => Banner [2] => DeepLink ) ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [advertiser-id] => 198699 [account-status] => Active [seven-day-epc] => 17.86 [three-month-epc] => 10.10 [language] => en [advertiser-name] => Wickers Sportswear, Inc. [program-url] => xhttp://www.wickers.com [relationship-status] => joined [mobile-tracking-certified] => false [network-rank] => 1 [primary-category] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [parent] => Sports & Fitness [child] => Apparel ) [performance-incentives] => false [actions] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [action] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Sale [type] => sale [id] => 435 [commission] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [default] => 7.00% ) ) ) [link-types] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [link-type] => Array ( [0] => Text Link [1] => Banner [2] => DeepLink [3] => Advanced Link ) ) )

When I loop thru this data, I am able to get value for the "language" element, however if I try to get value for "advertiser-id" field, I get the error "( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'". My guess is that dash (-) between advertiser and id is the cause of the issue as I have successully displayed value for the language element.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that big blob of crap exactly what you got back from the var_dump?  Check the HTML source; you should see a version of it that's much easier to read.

Comment: Please don't use `var_dump()` or similar to debug SimpleXML objects, as it's not always an accurate representation. In cases like this, the best idea is to paste in the actual XML you're parsing, and then people can reproduce the problem if they need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"advertiser-id" is not a valid identifier, due to the dash.  PHP is interpreting the dash as a minus sign, so `$advertiser->advertiser-id` is being parsed as `$advertiser->advertiser` minus the constant named `id`.

Try using `$advertiser->{'advertiser-id'}` instead.  That's one way to access properties whose names aren't valid identifiers.